# AWT: NullPointerException when creating icon

Tags: java, awt

Whenever I set an image as an icon I get an error.
Here is my Addemployee code:
https://pastebin.com/xnbXP1B2

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at InheritancePackage.AddEmployee.initComponents(AddEmployee.java:471)
    at InheritancePackage.AddEmployee.<init>(AddEmployee.java:96)
    at InheritancePackage.Menu.MainAddMouseClicked(Menu.java:554)
    at InheritancePackage.Menu$9.mouseClicked(Menu.java:269)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

The way I setup the icon inside the jlabel is through "Image Within Project" and if you check the project menu the picture package is included. All of the picture that are used are in the "picture" package.
[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Show you code of AddEmployee.java.

Comment: It should be added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Step by step solution:

1. Right clicking your project
2. Hover over "new" and select "folder"
3. Name your folder "src/main/resources"
4. Move all your images to that new folder
5. When selecting images for icons, go into that package of the new folder for the images.

After doing this, there will be no more null pointer and the images will transfer over when exporting it as a ZIP.

That should fix this problem because it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

`getResource()` doesn't find the image and returns `null`, which causes the problem in the Icon class. Check where you image actually is and use correct path.

Comment: I fixed the path to pictures and it still gives that error. This is so when I export the maven project, I want the icons to stay because I have already tried exporting it and the icons remove themselves on another computer because the path doesn't exist. Lastly, I cannot edit that area of the because its restricted and I am not allowed to edit it.

Comment: All resources that your application needs should be packaged to the JAR, not remain outside of it.

Comment: Sorry to consistently bother you, but I looked at how to make images inside a jar file, but I could not find it, I was wondering if you can me out?

Answer (score 0):

I notice , you have used absolute path here, cause it begins with /

```
jLabel18.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/InheritancePackage/Save_1.png")));
```

On your computer, the image is at the desired location:

```
/InheritancePackage/Save_1.png
```

but on different computer its not present at /InheritancePackage/Save_1.png, its relative to jar file and hence not found, thus NullPointerException for icon!!

Instead, you should be using relative path, try removing / at the begining and use:

```
InheritancePackage/Save_1.png
```

Comment: so I managed to edit the text, but it will gives the same error. Instead of "/InheritancePackage/Save_1.png" it is now "InheritancePackage/Save_1.png"

Comment: Is Save_1.png in Pictures folder? cause I don't see it in InheritancePackage folder in screenshot above!! if so, you need to use Pictures/Save_1.png instead.

Comment: Actually I fixed it to Pictures/save_1.png and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this error, As you are using Maven, By default Maven don't move resource from Java code to your compiled classes. So you can use this maven plugin to do that. after that we will not face this error.

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <!-- here the phase you need -->
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/ordg/pos/resources/</outputDirectory>
                  <resources>          
                    <resource>
                      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/ordg/pos/resources/</directory>
                      <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                  </resources>              
                </configuration>            
              </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
```